# Flutter: is calling setState() multiple times inefficient?

Tags: flutter

Lets say I have a method `onButtonPressed()` which calls method `a()` and then method `b()`. Both methods `a()` and `b()` contain a call to `setState()`:

```
void onButtonPressed() {
    ...
    a();
    ...
    b();
}

void a() {
    ...
    setState() {
        ...
    }
}

void b() {
    ...
    setState() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Does calling `setState()` twice cause the affected components to be rendered twice, or is Flutter optimized so that the components only get rendered once?

Comment: see what `setState` is doing [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L1137)

Answer (score 8):

If all of your `setState` calls happen within the same frame, then there's no issue.

The widget will rebuild once and only once.

Once a widget is marked as needing build, all subsequent calls to `setState` will do nothing but call the callback until a frame is scheduled and the build is done.

Comment: Can you elaborate on _within the same frame_? By frame you mean 1 of the 60 frames per second that are being rendered?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The only thing you should care of, is whether all calls to `setState` as done synchronously or are they separated by some futures.

Comment: so what's the difference?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here because currently I call setState((){ isLoading = true}) at the beginning of a function and then call setState((){ isLoading = false}) at the end. There are no async function in between but I was assuming that this will first set isLoading state to true which will trigger loading screen and then once all the functions completed, isLoading will be set back to false which I imagine will cause the loading screen to load just for a second. Is this not true?

Answer (score 3):

There is a tiny overhead that every call to a function call cost, but this is negligible.

This does not cause an additional overhead from or for the framework.

Answer (score -4):

You could do this

```
void onButtonPressed() {
  ...
  a();
  ...
  b();
  setState((){});
}
```

So you are calling setState in only one place

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid and why I asked this question.